# Amadeus flask wtforms Search autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: autocomplete, amadeus

Does anyone have an example of Amadeus search location autocomplete using flask and wtforms?
I cannot figure out how to show the locations in the drop-down menu to the user when he tries to type in the destination field. For Example, if he types 'New Yo" it should show him a drop-down menu with suggestions like New York - LGA, New York -JFK

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to integrate the API from self-service, to fetch the list of cities and airport names by IATA Code,  https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/airport-and-city-search

Comment: For answer's with link(s), it is advisable  to highlight the important details or provide a summary regarding what you found in the link you provided. Because time will come that the link will be unavailable/invalid.